# Laravel searching on hasmany relationship

Tags: php, laravel-5

I've code like this

```
Product Table
--id

Attributes
--id
--product_id
--type

AttributeMap
-id
--attribute_id
--product_id
```

Each product can have multiple attributes - like have 20 different sizes ,etc.

Now I want to search it using multiple parameters. For example size=23, color=56, etc.

How is it possible using nested queries?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: $productData = ProductsModel::where('products.status','=','active');
                $i=0;
                foreach ($resultArray->getArray() as $parameter)
                {
                    if($i==0 || $parameter['key'] == 'product_brands')
                    {
                        $productData->search($parameter['value']);
                    } else {
                        $productData->search($parameter['value']);
                    }
                    $i++;
                }

Comment: Where do you store values for product's attributes? And why are both Attributes and AttributesMap linked to Products? Isn't AttributeMap enough?

Comment: Because each product has multiple attributes. So a mapping needs to be done that which attribute are related to product. Values for product's attributes are stored in attributemap table

Comment: Where are the values stored exactly? I don't see any field in AttributeMap that could store it